# selecting text and value from dynamic datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-datalist

I'm trying to create an autocomplete box using data list. Here is what I do and want:

1. bind the datalist with response(key, value) from server
2. When I bind my data list I see both key and value, but I want to see only value. Question: How to display only value in datalist?
3. Whenever I select a value from the this dynamic data list, I want to show selected value and its text. Question: How to display the selected value and its corresponding key from datalist?

My Code:

```
<input type="text" id="tex_in"  list="dataList" />
                            <datalist id="dataList" >

                                   </datalist>

 if (query.length >= 4)
  {

        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: proxy,
                    data: JSON.stringify({"table" : table, "query" : query}),
                    success: function(){},
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType : "application/json",
                    success: function (response) {
                                  var data_response = 
                                 JSON.stringify(response)
                                 var data = JSON.parse(data_response);
                                 data.response.docs.forEach(function (el) {

                                    if (autoCan.length < 10)
                                    autoCan.push([el["key"], el["value"]]);

                                     });

                                 //console.log(autoCan);
                                  if (autoCan.length)
                                          {

                                          autoCan.forEach(function (el) {


                                          $('#dataList').append($("<option></option>").val(el[1]).html(el[0])); //



                                           });

// display selected key and value  from this datalist

                                            $("#dataList").click(function (){
                                             console.log($('#dataList option:selected').text());
                                            console.log($('#dataList').attr('value'));


                                            });




                                          }

                                 else {

                                        $('#dataList').modal('hide');
                                      }





                         },
                            error: function() {
                                 console.log("error at server");


                            }



                    });




   }

  else
  {
    $('#dataList').modal('hide');

    }
```

Comment: Please create a static runnable example reduced to the bare minimum code necessary to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score -1):

```js
starks = [{id: 1, name: 'Bran'}, {id: 2, name: 'Sansa'}, {id: 3, name: 'Arya'}]

starks.forEach(function(stark) {
  $('#selection').append('<option data-value="'+ stark.id+'" value="' + stark.name + '">' + stark.name + '</option>')
})



 $("#input").on('input', function (){
   var selectedValue = $(this).val();
   $('#value').text('Value: '+$('#selection [value="' + selectedValue + '"]').data('value'));
   $('#browser [value="' + selectedValue + '"]').data('value')
   $('#text').text('Text: '+selectedValue)
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text" list="selection"/>

<datalist id="selection">
</datalist>

<br/><br/>

<span id="value"></span><br/>
<span id="text"></span>
```

Comment: If i get it right, you are using select, but wat to use autocomplete box(dataList). A select tag will be present on ui even if i dont type in the text box.

Comment: I've just edited the code, I've set the key as a data attribute so it won't show your key on the datalist. When the user selects an option we know the retrieve the correct key from the data attribute based on the value the user selected.